# How do I scrape to csv in scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, scrapy

How do I scrape a page to csv? My csv does not appear or appears blank

I have ran: `scrapy crawl jobs -o output.csv` .  While the csv appears, nothing appears into it.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


from scrapy import cmdline
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl jobs".split())

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "jobs"
    allowed_domains = ["sfbay.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button next"]',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath('//span[@class="pl"]')
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item["title"] = titles.xpath("a/text()").extract()
            item["link"] = titles.xpath("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return(items)

    class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'csvexample'
        start_urls = ['C:/example.csv']
        delimiter = ','
        headers = ['Address', 'Website']
```

Comment: Another example.  https://pastebin.com/yyiunAX2 .  Same issue.  Blank Csv

Comment: Print `response`.  What does it contain?

Comment: @JohnZwinck For print(response) I don't get anything. https://pastebin.com/nZHtHs8X

Comment: If you can't print the response, perhaps Craigslist is blocking you.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Hmm.. unlikely as other example is doing similar thing.  print(response) at the end just does nothing.  Maybe my code is just wrong.  Hmmm

Comment: @JohnZwinck UH... Pycharm does not print text in console with scrapy.  What has the world come to when I can't use my favourite IDE with scrapy xD

Comment: IDE is uses only to develop code, after that we run it without IDE.

Comment: @furas Very true, I meant as in debugging scrapy though.  How do you generally do this?  Cmd is not really ideal  for debugging (or is this something you get used to?)

Comment: I normally doesn't use PyCharm but normat text editor. And mostly I can resolve every problem with `print(...)`, `print( type(...) )`

Comment: for small scripts use visual studio code, use pycharm on large projects where you need code traversal and lookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -- I think you have to export each item individually. You are creating a special instance of the item class each time and never actually returning the item. You are appending items to your list and then returning the list So it never goes through the item pipe lines. Also in your list for titles you said for titles in titles both plural. :

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


from scrapy import cmdline
# cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl jobs".split()) -- Not sure what this line achieves?

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "jobs"
    allowed_domains = ["sfbay.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo"]
    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button next"]',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath('//span[@class="pl"]')
        for title in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item["title"] = title.xpath("a/text()").extract_first()
            item["link"] = title.xpath("a/@href").extract_first()
            yield item
```

Comment: I'm still getting a blank csv after running that with: scrapy crawl jobs -o output.csv.  I am getting unresolved reference for: from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem -  https://pastebin.com/fnGSNQR3